# WCF 4 - Soap and REST endpoints

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap

I was looking at using the WCF REST Service Application template to host all of my RESTful web services, however, I would also like to be able to expose out my WCF services with a SOAP endpoint.

I can easily get my WCF RESTful services working in WCF 4 using the following example: http://christopherdeweese.com/blog2/post/drop-the-soap-wcf-rest-and-pretty-uris-in-net-4

Is this possible? I would imagine there should be a way in the Global.asax to wire up additional endpoints and specify if one is using basicHttpBinding. Do I need to not use the WCF REST Service Application template and create a standard Service Application and wire it all up via the config?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Have you tried adding a 'normal' service to that template?

Comment: can you clarify it you are trying to provide 2 endpoints, SOAP and REST or you want a RESTful service which sends SOAP? My answer would change if you mean the first because I believe you mean the second.

Comment: My goal is to have a single WCF service that has 2 endpoints, SOAP and REST.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although in most cases I wouldn't mix REST and SOAP endpoints, but I agree that in certain cases it's necessary. The answer to the question: yes, it's possible to mix them. There are two options you can use:

The call in Global.asax.cs which defines the route for the REST endpoint

```
`RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Service1", new WebServiceHostFactory(),   typeof(Service1)))`
```

defines essentially a service at the address /Service1. You can add a new "service", using the same service implementation, but using a different service host factory (instead of using WebServiceHostFactory, which defines a REST endpoint, you'd use your own):

```
public class SoapServiceHostFactory : ServiceHostFactory
{
    protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        ServiceHost host = base.CreateServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);
        ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = host.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
        if (smb == null)
        {
            smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
        }

        smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(serviceType, new BasicHttpBinding(), "soap");
        return host;
    }
}
```

And in global.asax.cs, RegisterRoutes:

```
    private void RegisterRoutes()
    {
        // Edit the base address of Service1 by replacing the "Service1" string below
        RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Service1", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(Service1)));

        RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("SoapService", new SoapServiceHostFactory(), typeof(Service1)));
    }
```

- If you actually want to have one "logical" service with two endpoints (I wouldn't recommend, since the previous approach is simple enough), you can again create a custom ServiceHostFactory, then in that factory you'd add two endpoints: one for REST (using WebHttpBinding/WebHttpBehavior), and one for SOAP (using BasicHttpBinding, for example).

Comment: This is actually perfect since I have a Global.asax that I am wiring up my REST services in.

Comment: I'm having an error: "The value could not be added to the collection, as the collection already contains an item of the same type: 'System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataBehavior'. This collection only supports one instance of each type." What is wrong with this?

Comment: The `SoapServiceHostFactory` in this example is adding a `ServiceMetadataBehavior` to the description, but in your case you already have it there (maybe coming from some default endpoint in the configuration). I updated the code snippet to work even in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I had to add a constructor to carlosfigueira's factory so it builds the endpoint from the Interface and not the Service itself:

```
public class SoapServiceHostFactory : ServiceHostFactory
{
    private Type serviceInterfaceType;

    public SoapServiceHostFactory(Type serviceInterfaceType) 
    {
        this.serviceInterfaceType = serviceInterfaceType;
    }

    protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
    {
        ServiceHost host = base.CreateServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);
        host.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior { HttpGetEnabled = true });
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(serviceInterfaceType, new BasicHttpBinding(), "soap");
        return host;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was also getting an exception like `The contract type MyClassSvc is not attributed with ServiceContractAttribute.  In order to define a valid contract, the specified type (either contract interface or service class) must be attributed with ServiceContractAttribute.` Weird because my service inherits from the interface and the interface has that attribute. Framework bug?

Answer (score 0):

I have a web service running where clients require both SOAP and REST access. You can define your REST URL templates using the WebGet and WebInvoke attributes.

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    RS DoSomething(RQ request); 
}

[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class Service : IService
{
    public RS DoSomething(RQ rq)
    {
        return new RS(rq);
    }
}
```

Then simply map the endpoints as required in the config

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Service" behaviorConfiguration="defaultBehavior">
        <endpoint address="soap11" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="IService" behaviorConfiguration="soapBehavior" />
        <endpoint address="rest" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IService" behaviorConfiguration="restBehavior"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restBehavior">
          <webHttp faultExceptionEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="soapBehavior">
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="defaultBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"  />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```